# Как сделать 301 редирект в .htaccess?

Tags: url, redirect, http-status-code-301

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать 301 редирект в .htaccess

С страниц такого плана

```
https://demo1.piwigo.com/picture?/1274/category/34-citrus_fruit
https://demo1.piwigo.com/picture?/1274/tags/69-citrus
https://demo1.piwigo.com/picture?/1274/tags/14-fruit
```

На

```
https://demo1.piwigo.com/picture?/1274
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, этот вариант подойдет

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^picture /picture?/%1 [NC,L]
```

Я не совсем помню настройки htaccess, поэтому только предполагаю